# Parse an xml array of simple values in go

Tags: arrays, xml, go, slice

I have an xml that looks like this:

```
<MyElement>
    <Ids>
        <int>1</int>
        <int>2</int>
    </Ids>
</MyElement>
```

I find it challenging to parse in go. I've tried the following

```
type MyElement struct {
  Ids int[] 
}
```

or even

```
type Ids struct {
  id int[] `xml:"int"`
}

type MyElement struct {
  Ids Ids
}
```

But it never get picked up.

The difficulty is in the fact that the elements are all called int and only store an int value, instead of the usual key/value pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the path the `int` elements:

```
type MyElement struct {
    Ids []int `xml:"Ids>int"`
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/HfyQzOiSqa

You can also do this in order not to repeat "Ids"

```
type MyElement struct {
    Ids []int `xml:">int"`
}
```

This functionality is mentioned in [`xml.Unmarshal`'s documentation](https://godoc.org/encoding/xml#Unmarshal):

> - If the XML element contains a sub-element whose name matches
>     the prefix of a tag formatted as "a" or "a>b>c", unmarshal
>     will descend into the XML structure looking for elements with the
>     given names, and will map the innermost elements to that struct
>     field. A tag starting with ">" is equivalent to one starting
>     with the field name followed by ">".